# Oracle Apex 5 File Browser Blob Creation

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm using APEX 5 for the first time and having issue trying to insert items into my blob table.

I searched for many guides about creating File Browse's storage type to BLOB columns, which allows me to add MIME_TYPE, FILENAME, and CHARSET etc into my table. I am trying to create both upload and download feature.

But one thing that's been really confusing is creating DML processes, I could not understand where they getting their primary key item from, I somewhat understand that the DML primary key column are supposed to be my table's primary key?Errors keep coming up when I try to upload. 
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj0G0.png

Any kind of help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Below is my table to store blob

```
CREATE TABLE  "MATERIALS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MATERIAL_NAME" VARCHAR2(400), 
    "FILENAME" VARCHAR2(350), 
    "M_COURSE_ID" VARCHAR2(68), 
    "MIME_TYPE" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "DOC_SIZE" NUMBER, 
    "CHARSET" VARCHAR2(128), 
    "LAST_UPDATE_DATE" DATE, 
    "CONTENT" BLOB, 
     CONSTRAINT "MATERIALS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )   NO INMEMORY
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the text of any error messages into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a item on your page to hold the `id` field. Your first process will populate it. I'm guessing you have a sequence?

1. Create a Hidden item, I'll call it `P1_ID`.
2. Your first process will populate it if it's empty. Create a process at the Processing step with a body of:

   `apex_util.set_session_state( 'P1_ID', mysequence.NEXTVAL );`
3. Your DML process must run *after* this step, so drag them around or change the sequence if necessary.
4. Now set the Primary Key Item value to P1_ID in your DML process.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,
I created a hidden item FILE_ID and populated it with the sequence that was created alongside my table MATERIALS_SEQ.
But now an error is still showing as follow: 1 
error has occurred Column FILE_ID not found in table MATERIALS.
Is my hidden item FILE_ID supposed to be created inside my MATERIALS table? or should there specifically be a place for my FILE_ID? thanks again

Comment: Why did you create FILE_ID, if column name is ID? Though, that doesn't matter - item's **source** should be named as a column, but it is confusing when you name the same thing with two different names. It is difficult to track what you did and why.